# Is there any TypeScript utility type to pick a property from another type and make it required?

Tags: typescript

Right now the only way I've found is the long expression `Pick...`... is there any shortend I'm not aware of?

```ts
type CustomerDetailsListProps = {
  emptyValue?: string,
};

type ListItemValueProps = {
  emptyValue: Pick<Required<CustomerDetailsListProps>, 'emptyValue'>['emptyValue'],
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NonNullable`:

```
type ListItemValueProps = {
  emptyValue: NonNullable<CustomerDetailsListProps["emptyValue"]>,
};

const a: ListItemValueProps = {} 
// Property 'emptyValue' is missing in type '{}' but required 
// in type 'ListItemValueProps'

const b: ListItemValueProps = { emptyValue: "" }
```

You could also use just use `Required` with `Pick` to create the whole object type in one line.

```
type ListItemValueProps = Required<Pick<CustomerDetailsListProps, "emptyValue">>
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=82&pln=9&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgZ2AewLYQE4BELAIYCWANggDIFIAKGyYCUAvFAN4CwAUFFBKmKAGp4icCAH4AXFCQYCAOwDmAGg4BfANwcOoSFHJIAksB6DhEarXpM2nbrwFCRkgHLJZTuESJ4ARkQgAeeCQ0TBx8YjIKYHM6AG0AIh4+EBMReIBdAD5ldnUtcGg9YENjBzMaOgAmRigAJQgARzgCDAgAE39KAgBjAGtAxBR0bFxCEiKYhEUoRLsUsvjMzM12btckKDxJIpLUVPKLGuYVKAB6U6gYzFAoAHIk+1NbqAooVAoEOXkX2ShtaFux2e3jgwCgrSaLXaPz+BTuOyMezKk1uHDWsg23m2UV2+0mR1syX2kni8SgKiAA)